# MySQLi Insert Statement placing NULL for variable

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

So I have the following code which is used to add a row to the respondent table, all working except when trying to add the value in of `Brand`:

```
$brand = 'Central';

function new_respondent() {
        global $link;
        $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO trespondent (brand, code) VALUES (?, uuid());");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "s", $brand);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
        $respondent_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($proc);
        mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
        mysqli_clean_connection($link);
}
```

This code works (to a point) adds a row in the table and adds in the `UUID` no problems but `brand` is going in as `NULL` - I'm trying to work out if I am missing something very obvious here!

Any and all suggestion welcome.

Comment: You're abusing global variables. Just pass stuff as function parameters.

Comment: `function new_respondent()` => `function new_respondent($link, $brand)` and pass those arguments along. `global` is a bad approach.

Comment: 'You're abusing global variables.' - can you elaborate?

Comment: @Homer_J Qirel just gave an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `$brand` to your `global`, since it's outside of the function:

```
global $link, $brand;
```

Alternatively, you can modify your function to accept `$brand` as parameter:

```
function new_respondent($brand) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you....I've been looking at this for the past 60 mins and couldn't see it!!! DOH!